# Zabbix installed from package, but no SNMP or Web Scenarios?

Tags: zabbix

I'm new to Zabbix but I'm loving the capabilities.  I installed on a fresh server (Debian Jessie) using the package and from following the instructions [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/installation/install_from_packages).  Today I just realized I don't have the capability to use the Web Scenario and SNMP functionality.  It looks like if I had downloaded and compiled from source, I could have enabled this using the arguments on the configuration step.

My question is:

Do I have to uninstall my current installation and compile from source to get this functionality? If so, should I expect having to start fresh (new db, configuration, templates, triggers, etc..)?

Also, am I correct in assuming that if I compile from source without uninstalling from package, not all files from the previous installion would be overwritten and I would have two side-by-side installations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, both of those features are available. To verify, check your server logfile when it has been just started up - the feature entries should say `YES`.

Note that there is no separate menu entry for web monitoring [since Zabbix 2.2](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/introduction/whatsnew220#templated_web_scenarios) - this is now available in host & template listings.

Comment: You are correct - I see that everything is enabled but I don't have any options for web scenarios or monitoring... Weird.  I'll have to get back to Googling to try and figure out why.

Comment: You might have been looking at some older manuals and expecting the main menu entry, maybe? Included that bit in the answer, too :)

Comment: You were correct. I was looking in all of the wrong places..